# script error on require "dijit/form/Select"

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

This code

```
require([ "dojo","dojo/request/script", "dojo/parser", "dojox/mobile", "dojox/mobile/compat", "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme",
              "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView",
              "dojox/mobile/ScreenSizeAware",
              "dojox/mobile/FixedSplitter",
              "dojox/mobile/ContentPane",


              "dijit/form/Select"
              ],

              function(dojo) {
```

generate a script error on adding Select. Why?
I try [this](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/Select.html) but don't works!

```
Error: multipleDefine


...on(h){return"[object Array]"==l.call(h)},g=function(h,a){if(h)for(var c=0;c<h.le...

dojo.js (line 2)
Error: scriptError
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete, self-contained example?  I don't think there's anything wrong with just what you posted.

Comment: Can you add point where you use modules and how because the error might be there

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in WL6 with the default dojo 1.9 library:

```
function dojoInit() {
require([ "dojo", "dojo/ready", "dojo/parser", "dojox/mobile", "dojo/dom", "dijit/registry", "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView",
        "dijit/form/Select" ], function(dojo, ready) {
    ready(function() {

        new dijit.form.Select({
            name : "select2",
            options : [ {label : "TN",value : "Tennessee"}, 
                        {label : "VA",value : "Virginia",selected : true}, 
                        {llabel : "WA",value : "Washington"}, 
                        {label : "FL",value : "Florida"}, 
                        {label : "CA",value : "California"} ]
        }).placeAt(dojo.byId(view0));
    });
});
}
```

There is no error, though the widget display seems messed up in the app.  (it works, but doesn't look right) Maybe it needs some css

Comment: None for the Select.  I just used the default generated dojo HTML that has a single view named view0.  The Select could be defined in the HTML instead of in the JS.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Could you post more details of what you are trying to do.  I did a simple declarative example (added "dijit/form/Select" to the require in JavaScript and the rest in html) Again, there was something funny with he layout, but there were no errors.  Are you trying to do something dynamic with a select that is declared in he html?

Comment: i write this in html <select name="select1" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
</select>    and doesn't works.Why? I follow the declarative example and doesn't works

Comment: Something strange.  That worked for me.  Are you on Worklight 6 (latest) and dojo 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

It usually means that you have a different version of dijit/form/Select defined somewhere and their clashing