# dijit/form/Select is not working properly in both Emulator and Simulator

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, dojo

I am using dijit/form/Select in my app to dynamically bind some data. I am able to bind the data to the Select element but problem is that my Select element is not rendering properly in both of my Emulator and simulator. I am using embedded dojo 1.9 in worklight and below are the code that I am using. Is there anything else that I need to add in my code to use dijit select ? I searched for this type of question in this forum and I found this link where the user is having same problem but that is unanswered.

[script error on require "dijit/form/Select"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082652/script-error-on-require-dijit-form-select?rq=1)

[image: in Emulator]
[image: in simulator]

My HTML code-

```
     <select  id="selectCity" name="selectCity" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">

     </select>
```

my script code-

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true,   parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's because theming in `dojox/mobile` is different from theming in `dijit`. To use a dropdown using `dijit` modules, you would have to configure a [a theme](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/themes.html). Usually this means you need to import a CSS file and add a class to the parent element (most common practice is by adding it to your `<body>` tag). But these themes are **not** device specific.

A better solution would be by using the `dojox/mobile/ComboBox`, more info can be found at the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/ComboBox.html).